# How to change ionic 3 tab size and color?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, css-position

[image similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNUMN.jpg)

```html
<ion-tabs >
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"  tabIcon="logo-buffer"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"  tabIcon="ios-folder"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"  tabIcon="md-add-circle"  ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root"  tabIcon="ios-people"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root"  tabIcon="ios-chatbubbles"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

how to change size and color of center icon in ionic 3 ??

Answer (score 2):

You can add class in `<ion-tab>` some thing like

```
 <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" class="my-add-button" tabIcon="md-add-circle"  ></ion-tab>
```

and write some scss for your own class in `.scss` file some thing like

```
.my-add-button {
  .....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try code like

```
<ion-tab [color]="yourColor">
```

In your ts file

```
let yourColor = "primary"; //you can change to secondary, danger, warning, etc.
```

Edit or add your custom color in `src/theme/variables.scss`

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  // your custom:     #273648
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way(and right way provived by ionic documentation) to change the size of the tabs is using the sass variables they provide on the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/).

```
$tabs-md-tab-max-width:240px;
$tabs-md-tab-min-height: 49px;
$tabs-md-tab-font-size: 13px;
$tabs-md-tab-icon-size: 14px;
```

Where "md" stands for material design, if you change it for "ios" will only change it for ios.